# How to (or why cannot) define complex conjugate in the structure $(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z},+)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z},+)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit, be a structure with an only operation $+$, the ordinary addition in $\mathbb{Z}$, and with no constant symbols. In this structure, the number zero and the inverse of any number are definable (I think), for they can be defined as $\forall x(x=0 \leftrightarrow\forall y(x+y=y))$ and $\forall x\forall y(x=-y\leftrightarrow x+y=0)$. Then is there any way to define the complex conjugate of any number or define some specific complex numbers, like $i$, $1+i$, etc., within the given structure?

Comment: Why, yes of course: it is complex conjugation, restricted to this group (as a ring, it is called the *Gaussian integers*).

Comment: The lattice by itself has symmetry on replacing "1" by "i" and vice versa; you have to break this symmetry to define complex conjugation, by making a distinction between "1" and "i".

Comment: @Bernard The goal is to define the operation inside the structure, in the sense of model theory; not to describe it in general.

Comment: I think yoi cannot define it on the group structure, as there is a group isomorphism sending $i\to 1$ and $1\to i$. However, if you consider the ring $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, you can define $i$ as one of the two elements satisfying $x^2+1 = 0$. And it would be the best you can get, since conjugation is a field isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ and so in a way, $i$ and $-i$ are indistinguishable

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Sorry, this was not clear to me.

Comment: @Max: It seems that once again Noah was quicker. ;)

Comment: The more interesting question is to ask about the ring of Gaussian intergers, where multiplication also is present, and in this case, things are more subtle.  A student in my logic class this semester happened to write his term paper on topics close to this, and I'll ask him to post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

Remember that for a function $f: \mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ (or indeed any function or relation in general) to be definable in $\mathcal{M}$, it must be fixed by automorphisms: if $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$, we must have that $f(\alpha(m))=\alpha(f(m))$ for all $m\in\mathcal{M}$. **Note that this is not a sufficient condition - it's a good exercise to prove this.**

Now observe that since we don't have the multiplicative structure on $\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ in this case, the "switching" map $\alpha: a+bi\mapsto b+ai$ is an automorphism of the structure; but it doesn't preserve conjugation, since e.g. $$conj(\alpha(1-2i))=conj(-2+i)=-2-i\quad\mbox{ but }\quad\alpha(conj(1-2i))=\alpha(1+2i)=2+i.$$

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me the last $+i$ breaks the lines. You might want to fix that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hm, mine works, but feel free to edit if you see how to improve it